# Jhipster: Why I can't see metamodel entity generated from jdl file?

Tags: jhipster

I'm new in Jhipster and I'm trying to generate MetaModel entities with jdl file from Jhipster. When I run command to generate entity, my Eclipse doesn't show MetaModel entities. Can anyone had the same problem? Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either build with maven/gradle or configure Eclipse to run the annotation processor as documented in
[JHipster documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide-eclipse/#-configuring-eclipse)
and/or [JPA Static Metamodel Generator documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/topical/html_single/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html#_usage_within_the_ide)